# Outlook embedded picture from Excel not showing in mail outside organisation

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

I am using a macro to compose a report based on an excel file. The macro uses a body with text and a picture (png) from an predefined Excel range.
This used to work perfect but now I have to share the report outside of my organization i get feedback that the image is not showing.

Does anybody know if this is due to the macro or not?
I have tested this also to my hotmail and gmail accounts and it is not showing there as well?

[image]

```
Sub Mail_()
Dim OutApp As Object
Dim OutMail As Object
Dim strbody As String
Dim SigString As String
Dim Signature As String
Dim Adm As Worksheet
Dim Body As String
Dim Body2 As String
Dim Body3 As String
Dim Body4 As String
Dim rngToPicture As Range
Dim rng2 As Range
Dim Weeknr As String
Dim strTempFilePath As String
Dim strTempFileName As String
    

Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)
Set Adm = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Uit")
Set rngToPicture = Adm.Range("X13:AT65")

Adm.Activate
ActiveWindow.Zoom = 100

strTempFileName = "RangeAsPNG"
              
Weeknr = Adm.Range("AF3").Text
Body = Adm.Range("X6:X6").Text
Body2 = Adm.Range("X8:X8").Text
Body3 = Adm.Range("X9:X9").Text
Body4 = Adm.Range("X11:X11").Text

    

strbody = "<BODY style=font-size:10pt;font-family:Verdana>" & Body & _
"<br><br>" & Body2 & "<br>" & Body3 & "<br><br>" & Body4 & "<br><br>"

'Change only Mysig.htm to the name of your signature
SigString = Environ("appdata") & _
            "\Microsoft\Handtekeningen\Servicekantoor.htm"

    Signature = GetBoiler(SigString)


On Error Resume Next

With OutMail
    .to = "Mailinglist@list.com"
    .CC = ""
    .BCC = ""
    .Subject = "Weekly report " & Weeknr
    
    'Create the range as a PNG file and store it in temp folder
    Call createPNG(rngToPicture, strTempFileName)
  
    'Embed the image in Outlook
    strTempFilePath = Environ$("temp") & "\" & strTempFileName & ".png"
    .Attachments.Add strTempFilePath, olByValue, 0
    .HTMLBody = strbody & "<br><br>" & "<img src='cid:" & strTempFileName & ".png' 
style='border:0'>" & "<br><br>" & Signature
    .Recipients.ResolveAll
     .Display 

End With

On Error GoTo 0
Set OutMail = Nothing
Set OutApp = Nothing
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are close - the `cid` in the `src` attribute must be not the file name (which is not visible to the outside users), but some value that matches the `PR_ATTACH_CONTENT_ID` property on the attachment:

```
strTempFilePath = Environ$("temp") & "\" & strTempFileName & ".png"
set Attach = .Attachments.Add(strTempFilePath, olByValue)
Attach.PropertyAccessor.SetProperty "http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x3712001F", "MyCid"
.HTMLBody = strbody & "<br><br>" & "<img src='cid:MyCid' style='border:0'>" & "<br><br>" & Signature
```

Comment: Thanks for helping, but i dont think i can follow here. The line Attach.PropertyAccesor gives a syntaxis error

Comment: Get rid of `(` and `)` - VB does not like parentheses when calling a sub.

Comment: Got it working now, thanks for helping out!